# Programmatically restore the Windows system to a previously created Restore Point

Tags: c#, c++

I have created a system restore point in C++.

My question is, is it possible to programmatically restore the Windows system to a previously created restore point, or we have to use the Windows tool?

Comment: Use System.Management to execute the [SystemRestore.Restore() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378925%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) .  This is a pretty bad idea btw.